# I can't access my WildFly 10.1.0 running on Oracle Linux 6.9 in VMware vSphere Client

Tags: linux, port, wildfly, iptables, application-server

I have WildFly 10.1.0 installed in my Oracle Linux 6.9

- My Windows IP address = `172.28.61.47`
- My Oracle Linux address = `192.168.50.58`

To access my Oracle Linux I used Teraterm Software using the `Host = 192.168.6.253` with `Port = 2258`

I already changed the default localhost address with my Linux IP address in `wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`.

I can't execute these commands because they are not enabled in Oracle Linux 6.9:
These two ports are the default port after installing WildFly 10.1.0.
These commands will enable WildFly to be accessed outside the network, using its default port.

- `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent`
- `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9990/tcp --permanent`

I tried adding port using:

- `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`
- `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9990 -j ACCEPT`

and even, stopping my `iptables` just to open all ports but nothing gonna happen. All ports policy are set to `ACCEPT` .I spent 3 days for solving these problem and still the problem exist.

To access the WildFly in Windows I used:

- `http://192.168.50.58/8080`

  Is there something I forgot to configure?

Comment: Did you really use `http://192.168.50.58/8080` literally? Because it should be `http://192.168.50.58:8080`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must access the WildFly Application Server using http://192.168.6.253:8080. If port 8080 was used then you need to redirect the port.